# How to remove the "See What's New" tile on Chromebook launcher

Tags: google-chrome, chromebook

Since a recent update to 81.0.4044.94, my Pixelbook Go keeps showing a **See what's new on Chromebook** tile in the recent apps list of the Launcher.

This keeps maintaining the first slot in the list even though I never click it.

How can I get rid of it?

[image: Screenshot]